# Why don't see repositories on the azure on the deployment setup?

Tags: azure

I am trying to set up deployment from git repo to azure.

Select the Github as source
[image]

Select build provider, actually I have tried both of them, because have no idea why repos is missing on the next step
[image]

This is screen, where I am trying to select the repo. Dropdown is empty.

[image]

This is screen from used github account, I have enabled all permissions for Azure.
[image]

I have checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment#option-1-use-app-service-kudu-build-server and this https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Investigating-continuous-deployment

Comment: Do you have any repositories under the particular org?

Comment: @Sajeetharan sure, there is one private repository

Comment: can you paste a screenshot of the source selection

Comment: @Sajeetharan done

Comment: are you trying this on the portal?

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes, you are right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206263/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-nikita).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below,

**`Navigate to Azure Portal -> Search for "Devops Projects" -> Create a New Project -> Import your code from Git`**